# I can't figure out the "Java InputMismatchException errors" in my code

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

In my code,I use "\n" as the delimiter, because there may be some 'sapce' in the user's input string. But a exception appeared.I am new to Java and I'm confused.So I'm very grateful to you for helping me out.

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\n");

        System.out.print("Please enter your ID:");
        int id=scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter your address:");
        String address=scanner.next();
    }

}
```

And the output:

```
Please enter your ID:20151212
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at learning.ScannerDemo.main(ScannerDemo.java:12)
```

Comment: `I use "\n" as the delimiter` This is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use `\n` as a delimiter, simply cast the text you're getting after trimming it.

---

### Solution

```
int id = Integer.valueOf(scanner.next().trim());
```

Or simply get rid of the delimiter.

Comment: Each time I use both the next() and the nextInt(), I need to get the int in this way?(cast the text,trim it and then convert it)

Comment: @KenkonHu If you're using `nextInt()` with the delimiter, it will always throw you an exception. If you're not using the delimiter, use these methods normally. :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the delimiter causes the issue - nextInt looks for the "\n" as part of the expected format, but it has already been consumed by the scanner.

If you want a more end-user fiendly approach, you're probably better off scanning for the next string, trim it and convert it to Integer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use scanner.nextLine() then trim() and convert to int.

Answer (score 0):

Since line terminator vary with OS.

- Windows system use "\r\n"
- Linux system use "\n"

So if you are running your code on windows, you should use "\r\n" as delimiter.
But there is a better option provided by java.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

so you should use

```
scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```